# Assign Custom Permission in Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, validation-rule, failing-tests, custom-permission

I have a validation rule

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Submission_Handover_Process_Status__c, 'Awaiting Validation'),
    ISCHANGED(Submission_Handover_Process_Status__c),
    NOT($Permission.Submission_Handover)
)
```

I have permission set with the above custom permission set:

[image: Permission set Screenshot]

My issue is when I am trying to assign the permission set to the user I am creating in the test class to bypass the validation, but that validation is always getting fired because of the Permission, resulting in test failures.

```
User usr = wtclm_UTIL_TestDataFactory.insertTestUser(DAL_Profile.PROFILE_SYS_ADMIN, DAL_User.USER_TYPE_STANDARD);
        System.runAs(usr) {
            PermissionSet submissionPermissionSet = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'PermsetName'];
            if (submissionPermissionSet != null) { insert new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = usr.id, PermissionSetId = submissionPermissionSet.Id);claim.Submission_Handover_Process_Status__c = wtclm_ClaimsSelector.HANDOVER_STATUS_AWAITING_VALIDATION;
        update claim;
}
```

Comment: That is how you would do it. Just a note, `if (submissionPermissionSet != null)` is equivalent to `if (true)` and can be removed. SOQL never returns `null`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson But it is not working for me it works only when I assigned the custom permission via the profile

Comment: on which object do you have this validation rule?

Comment: It is on Case Object

Comment: One thing that stands out is, it is odd to use `runAs` to insert the `PermissionSetAssignment`. It might indicate you used it there _instead_ of where you need it, which is the operation against `Case`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Then in that case I am facing MIXED_DML error if I am assigning permission set outside the runAs. Even though I tried to not create the user and instead assign the permission set to myself but in that case also same MIXED_DML error.

Comment: You seem to be missing my point. You _need_ to use `runAs` around your operation against `Case`.

Comment: see: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/353856/2602 for code sample

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, I am doing the same I have updated the code snippet

Comment: try creating permissionSetAssignment record before system.runAs(), for example - 
`User usr = wtclm_UTIL_TestDataFactory.insertTestUser(DAL_Profile.PROFILE_SYS_ADMIN, DAL_User.USER_TYPE_STANDARD);`
  `PermissionSet ps= [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'PermsetName'];
            if (ps!= null) { insert new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = usr.id, PermissionSetId = ps.Id);
}`

        System.runAs(usr) {
      claim.Submission_Handover_Process_Status__c = wtclm_ClaimsSelector.HANDOVER_STATUS_AWAITING_VALIDATION;
        update claim;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to do it by assigning the permission set in test setup method (i.e. the one with the @testSetup annotation).

Comment: Can you expand on this a little? You mean in a method marked @testSetup right?

Comment: @MattLacey Exactly